# Is there a fast way to re-format and compile odd data in Excel using VBA or R?

Tags: r, excel, vba, merging-data, reformatting

I have over 200 sheets in an Excel workbook that are each formatted in a really odd way and I need to figure out how to compile all the data that I need into a single master sheet. I only need the values from certain cells and ranges (shown in the code below). I'd like the final compiled sheet to be in long-form (see attached image).

There is an attached image that is an example of the format of each sheet - it contains all the cells but does not contain any actual data. In reality, there is a lot of data - some sheets have >1000 rows.

I tried to use a function in R to read in all the sheets as separate data frames so that I could merge them but I couldn't get it to work. I then tried to use VBA, but I'm not familiar with the syntax. Here's what I came up with:

```
Sub Copy_Example()

  Dim J As Integer
    Dim s As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(1).Select
    Worksheets.Add ' add a sheet in first place
    Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D9").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Combined").Range("A2")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E2").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Combined").Range("B2")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E3").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Combined").Range("C2")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E4").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Combined").Range("D2")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E5").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Combined").Range("E2")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C22:C2000").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Combined").Range("F1")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E22:E2000").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Combined").Range("G1")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F22:F2000").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Combined").Range("H1")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G22:G2000").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Combined").Range("I1")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H22:H2000").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Combined").Range("J1")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("I22:I2000").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Combined").Range("K1")

End Sub
```

This VBA will copy and paste the correct columns and ranges into a newly created worksheet only for Sheet 2. I tried to integrate additional snippets of code so that this would run through all sheets in the workbook and paste the data below the last line previously added but I can't get it to work. I would also love to be able to add a column with the name of the sheet that the data has been copied from.

If anyone can help me with this, using either R or VBA, I would really appreciate it.

[This is an example of the format of each sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcVnm.png)

[This is an example of what I'd like the master compiled sheet to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0eQB.png)

Comment: From what i can see, you are only copying to **Sheet2**. What are these `additional snippets` that you tried?. You could simply loop through all sheets in your workbook using a loop: `For Each oWS In Thisworkbook.Worksheets` (where `oWS` is a `Worksheet` variable)

Comment: @Zac I tried to use this instead but it wasn't working: `For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` `If s.Name <> Combined.Name Then` `Set CopyRng = s.Range("D9", "E2" "E3", etc)`

Comment: I also tried just putting  `For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` `If s.Name <> Combined.Name Then` above the code in the description above and that didn't work either.

Comment: Try changing your `IF` statement to: `If s.Name <> "Combined" Then`

Comment: That creates the combined data sheet and puts all the correct cells in the correct spot but only from Sheet 2. What do I need to change so that `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D9").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Combined").Range("A2")` refers to all worksheets instead of just "Sheet 2"? When I use `Set CopyRng = s.Range("D9", "E2" "E3", etc)` the code just doesn't run at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code

```
Sub CopyToCombined()

    Dim oComWS As Worksheet, oWS As Worksheet
    Dim iLR As Long: iLR = 1

    ' Add New sheet as "Combined"
    Set oComWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    oComWS.Name = "Combined"

    ' Loop through all sheets in the workbook and copy details in Combined sheet
    For Each oWS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If oWS.Name <> "Combined" Then
            With oWS
                oComWS.Range("A" & iLR).Value = .Range("A3").Value
                oComWS.Range("B" & iLR).Value = .Range("B5").Value
                oComWS.Range("C" & iLR).Value = .Range("C26").Value
            End With
            iLR = iLR + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Above code will go through all sheets in your workbook and copy the relevant data (obviously you will have to change what you want to copy)

**EDIT 1:**
As per requirement, below code should update the **`Combined`** as you requested

```
Sub CopyToCombined()

    Dim oComWS As Worksheet, oWS As Worksheet
    Dim iLR As Long: iLR = 1
    Dim iC As Long
    Dim aCleanArray As Variant, aMyRange As Variant, aColumn As Variant

    ' Add New sheet as "Combined"
    Set oComWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    oComWS.Name = "Combined"

    ' Set arrays
    aMyRange = Array("C20:C50", "D20:D50")  ' <-- Set all your ranges here (i.e. "C22:C2000", "E22:E2000", ...)
    aColumn = Array("C", "D")               ' <-- Set the columns here (i.e. "F", "G", ...)

    ' Loop through all sheets in the workbook and copy details in Combined sheet
    For Each oWS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If oWS.Name <> "Combined" Then
            With oWS
                oComWS.Range("A" & iLR).Value = .Range("A2").Value
                oComWS.Range("B" & iLR).Value = .Range("B2").Value

                For iC = LBound(aMyRange) To UBound(aMyRange)
                    aCleanArray = CleanUpArray(.Range(aMyRange(iC)).Value)
                    oComWS.Range(aColumn(iC) & iLR & ":" & aColumn(iC) & (iLR + UBound(aCleanArray))).Value = Application.Transpose(aCleanArray)
                Next
            End With
            iLR = oComWS.Range(aColumn(0) & oComWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Function CleanUpArray(aIncomigArray As Variant) As Variant
    Dim aTemp() As Variant
    Dim iC As Long

    ReDim aTemp(0 To 0)

    For iC = LBound(aIncomigArray) To UBound(aIncomigArray)
        If Not IsEmpty(aIncomigArray(iC, 1)) Then
            aTemp(UBound(aTemp)) = aIncomigArray(iC, 1)
            ReDim Preserve aTemp(UBound(aTemp) + 1)
        End If
    Next

    ReDim Preserve aTemp(UBound(aTemp) - 1)
    CleanUpArray = aTemp

End Function
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This almost works! It copies and pastes that data that is in only one cell (Ex. D9=Name) perfectly. It doesn't copy the columns that have ranges (it would need to create more than one row of data corresponding to each participant; Ex. "C22:C2000"). Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Are you expecting more than 1 line per patient? I'm presuming that your sheet with original data only holds data for 1 patient? I cant see that in the screen print you provided

Comment: No! Each sheet is data for a separate person and while all of the columns are named the same way and are in the same location, they are not all the same number of rows.

Comment: As each patient can have multiple rows, we need to cater for that. I will post something as and when i get some time. If you can't wait, you could try capturing your range for each patient in and array, removing blanks and then pasting the array